# What am I doing wrong in programming SHA-256 in Java?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha256

I am following the official NIST documentation, but I am unable to get the same result as Java's built-in MessageDigest class. For example, the string "This is being used to test SHA-2" produces 00c4f24db568535c8e00fe22f51200b6f3c600601dd8d749cfd9b91ac2307300afe39444 in this program. In the MessageDigest class, it is 32553c5e02e27bdcc4bf72210d7f07be2ad1e27f6c253e75608722322172062d. Did I make any mistakes?

```
public class SHA_256 {

private byte[] data;
private byte[] padded;
private int blocks;
final private int word_size = 32;
final private BigInteger modulo = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(word_size);
private BigInteger m[][];
private BigInteger w[] = new BigInteger[64];
private BigInteger k[] = new BigInteger[64];
private BigInteger h0;
private BigInteger h1;
private BigInteger h2;
private BigInteger h3;
private BigInteger h4;
private BigInteger h5;
private BigInteger h6;
private BigInteger h7;
private byte[] digest;

public SHA_256() {
    initConstants();
}

public SHA_256(byte[] input) throws IOException {
    initConstants();
    computeHash(input);
}

private void initConstants() {
    k[0] = new BigInteger("428a2f98", 32);
    k[1] = new BigInteger("71374491", 32);
    k[2] = new BigInteger("b5c0fbcf", 32);
    k[3] = new BigInteger("e9b5dba5", 32);
    k[4] = new BigInteger("3956c25b", 32);
    k[5] = new BigInteger("59f111f1", 32);
    k[6] = new BigInteger("923f82a4", 32);
    k[7] = new BigInteger("ab1c5ed5", 32);
    k[8] = new BigInteger("d807aa98", 32);
    k[9] = new BigInteger("12835b01", 32);
    k[10] = new BigInteger("243185be", 32);
    k[11] = new BigInteger("550c7dc3", 32);
    k[12] = new BigInteger("72be5d74", 32);
    k[13] = new BigInteger("80deb1fe", 32);
    k[14] = new BigInteger("9bdc06a7", 32);
    k[15] = new BigInteger("c19bf174", 32);
    k[16] = new BigInteger("e49b69c1", 32);
    k[17] = new BigInteger("efbe4786", 32);
    k[18] = new BigInteger("0fc19dc6", 32);
    k[19] = new BigInteger("240ca1cc", 32);
    k[20] = new BigInteger("2de92c6f", 32);
    k[21] = new BigInteger("4a7484aa", 32);
    k[22] = new BigInteger("5cb0a9dc", 32);
    k[23] = new BigInteger("76f988da", 32);
    k[24] = new BigInteger("983e5152", 32);
    k[25] = new BigInteger("a831c66d", 32);
    k[26] = new BigInteger("b00327c8", 32);
    k[27] = new BigInteger("bf597fc7", 32);
    k[28] = new BigInteger("c6e00bf3", 32);
    k[29] = new BigInteger("d5a79147", 32);
    k[30] = new BigInteger("06ca6351", 32);
    k[31] = new BigInteger("14292967", 32);
    k[32] = new BigInteger("27b70a85", 32);
    k[33] = new BigInteger("2e1b2138", 32);
    k[34] = new BigInteger("4d2c6dfc", 32);
    k[35] = new BigInteger("53380d13", 32);
    k[36] = new BigInteger("650a7354", 32);
    k[37] = new BigInteger("766a0abb", 32);
    k[38] = new BigInteger("81c2c92e", 32);
    k[39] = new BigInteger("92722c85", 32);
    k[40] = new BigInteger("a2bfe8a1", 32);
    k[41] = new BigInteger("a81a664b", 32);
    k[42] = new BigInteger("c24b8b70", 32);
    k[43] = new BigInteger("c76c51a3", 32);
    k[44] = new BigInteger("d192e819", 32);
    k[45] = new BigInteger("d6990624", 32);
    k[46] = new BigInteger("f40e3585", 32);
    k[47] = new BigInteger("106aa070", 32);
    k[48] = new BigInteger("19a4c116", 32);
    k[49] = new BigInteger("1e376c08", 32);
    k[50] = new BigInteger("2748774c", 32);
    k[51] = new BigInteger("34b0bcb5", 32);
    k[52] = new BigInteger("391c0cb3", 32);
    k[53] = new BigInteger("4ed8aa4a", 32);
    k[54] = new BigInteger("5b9cca4f", 32);
    k[55] = new BigInteger("682e6ff3", 32);
    k[56] = new BigInteger("748f82ee", 32);
    k[57] = new BigInteger("78a5636f", 32);
    k[58] = new BigInteger("84c87814", 32);
    k[59] = new BigInteger("8cc70208", 32);
    k[60] = new BigInteger("90befffa", 32);
    k[61] = new BigInteger("a4506ceb", 32);
    k[62] = new BigInteger("bef9a3f7", 32);
    k[63] = new BigInteger("c67178f2", 32);
}

private void initHashValues() {
    h0 = new BigInteger("6a09e667", 32);
    h1 = new BigInteger("bb67ae85", 32);
    h2 = new BigInteger("3c6ef372", 32);
    h3 = new BigInteger("a54ff53a", 32);
    h4 = new BigInteger("510e527f", 32);
    h5 = new BigInteger("9b05688c", 32);
    h6 = new BigInteger("1f83d9ab", 32);
    h7 = new BigInteger("5be0cd19", 32);
}

private void padding() {
    if (data.length % 64 < 56) {
        padded = new byte[64*(data.length/64 + 1)];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, padded, 0, data.length);
        padded[data.length] = (byte) 0b10000000;
    }
    else {
        padded = new byte[64*(data.length/64 + 2)];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, padded, 0, data.length);
        padded[data.length] = (byte) 0b10000000;
    }
    byte[] length = new byte[8]; //64-bit representation of the length of the data
    ByteBuffer.wrap(length).putInt(data.length);
    System.arraycopy(length, 0, padded, padded.length - 9, length.length);
    blocks = padded.length/64;
}

private void parsing() {
    m = new BigInteger[blocks][16];
    int index = 0;
    byte[] word = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            System.arraycopy(padded, index, word, 0, 4);
            m[i][j] = new BigInteger(word);
            index += 4;
        }
    }
}

public void computeHash(byte[] input) throws IOException {
    data = input;
    initHashValues();
    padding();
    parsing();

    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
            if (t <= 15) {
                w[t] = m[i][t];
            }
            else {
                w[t] = add(l_sigma1(w[t-2]), w[t-7]);
                w[t] = add(w[t], l_sigma0(w[t-15]));
                w[t] = add(w[t], w[t-16]);
            }
        }

        BigInteger a = h0;
        BigInteger b = h1;
        BigInteger c = h2;
        BigInteger d = h3;
        BigInteger e = h4;
        BigInteger f = h5;
        BigInteger g = h6;
        BigInteger h = h7;

        BigInteger t1;
        BigInteger t2;

        for (int t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
            t1 = add(h, sigma1(e));
            t1 = add(t1, ch(e, f, g));
            t1 = add(t1, k[t]);
            t1 = add(t1, w[t]);
            t2 = add(sigma0(a), maj(a, b, c));
            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = add(d, t1);
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = add(t1, t2);
        }

        h0 = add(a, h0);
        h1 = add(b, h1);
        h2 = add(c, h2);
        h3 = add(d, h3);
        h4 = add(e, h4);
        h5 = add(f, h5);
        h6 = add(g, h6);
        h7 = add(h, h7);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(h0.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h1.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h2.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h3.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h4.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h5.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h6.toByteArray());
    outputStream.write(h7.toByteArray());
    digest = outputStream.toByteArray();
}

public byte[] getDigest() {
    return digest;
}

private BigInteger add(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) { //Addition modulo 2^32
    return x.add(y).mod(modulo);
}

private BigInteger rotateRight(BigInteger x, int n) {
    return x.shiftRight(n).or(x.shiftLeft(word_size-n));
}

private BigInteger ch(BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger z) {
    return x.and(y).xor(x.not().and(z));
}

private BigInteger maj(BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger z) {
    return x.and(y).xor(x.and(z)).xor(y.and(z));
}

private BigInteger sigma0(BigInteger x) {
    return rotateRight(x, 2).xor(rotateRight(x, 13)).xor(rotateRight(x, 22));
}

private BigInteger sigma1(BigInteger x) {
    return rotateRight(x, 6).xor(rotateRight(x, 11)).xor(rotateRight(x, 25));
}

private BigInteger l_sigma0(BigInteger x) {
    return rotateRight(x, 7).xor(rotateRight(x, 18)).xor(x.shiftRight(3));
}

private BigInteger l_sigma1(BigInteger x) {
    return rotateRight(x, 17).xor(rotateRight(x, 19)).xor(x.shiftRight(10));
}
}
```

Comment: why did you choose 32 as radix in constants initialization? I guess they are hex numbers, so use 16 instead

Comment: Why are you using `BigInteger`?

Comment: Java integer types (`int` types) - with all their drawbacks - are perfectly suited to 32-bit algorithms such as SHA-256. Doing this with `BigInteger` is where madness lies. Anyway, to debug this, use another implementation and print out intermediate values (in hex) and then compare.

Comment: I fixed the radix on the hex values. I got confused because those are 32-bit values. I think the problem may be with the padding. It says to add a 64-bit binary representation of the length of the input data in bits. In this code, I accidentally made it the length in bytes. So I fixed that, but it's still not working. I tried converting the length from both an int and long value to a byte array using a ByteBuffer.

Comment: Addition in SHA-256 is performed modulo 2^32, and the maximum value of an unsigned integer is 2^32 - 1, so how would I do that using ints?

Comment: @metroidsocrates The modulo 2^32 means having values from 0 (zero!!!) to 2^32 - 1. The fact that Java uses values of -2^31 to 2^31-1 doesn't make a difference as signed, two-complement calculations are identical to unsigned operations. Note that SHA-256 has been optimized for 32 bit calculations (and SHA-512 has been optimized for 64 bit, which is why it can be actually *faster* than SHA-256 on 64-bit CPU's). Take a look at other implementations such as Bouncy Castle if you're not convinced. `BigInteger` is **never** used for symmetric crypto in libraries.

Comment: Modulo 2^32 means values within 0..2^32-1 (just like base 10 means digits between 0 and 9). The modulo value itself is out of range. Also note that performing modulo operations can be optimized. They are mathematically equivalent to performing the operation followed by the modulus, but there is a reason why there is a `modPow` method in Java's `BigInteger`. If you use `int` variables, the modulus 2^32 operation is *implied*.